# How we can use Context class?

Tags: android, android-context

I am an android developer.I am just doing R&D on context. I know we can extend any class with Context class but I am not able to find out for which functionality We should use this. Can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interface which allows you to access various application components.. and it also is responsible for accessing data of other applications..

Comment: have you made any class which extends context

Comment: I don't have to do that.. since Activity() class already does it.. i use Activity() class straight away.. if u extend it u may have implement its methods..